# How to display .ico files in the media library

Tags: media-library, favicon

I have added a `.ico` mime type into my WordPress site and I'm able to upload favicon files. But the media library only displays the `default.png` image for these images and also in the Customizer. How can I get WordPress to display these favicon images, in the media library and the customizer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Update: It looks like this will be supported in 5.0+. See ticket [#43458](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43458)*

### The default

This is how the *favicon* (`.ico`) files show up in the *Media Grid* view:

[image: default]

This is the corresponding part of the micro template:

```
<# } else if ( 'image' === data.type && data.sizes ) { #>
    <div class="centered">
        <img src="{{ data.size.url }}" draggable="false" alt="" />
    </div>
<# } else { #>
    <div class="centered"> 
        <# if ( data.image && data.image.src && data.image.src !== data.icon ) { #>
           <img src="{{ data.image.src }}" class="thumbnail" draggable="false" />
        <# } else { #>
            <img src="{{ data.icon }}" class="icon" draggable="false" />
        <# } #>
    </div>
    <div class="filename">
        <div>{{ data.filename }}</div>
    </div>
<# } #>
```

where `data.sizes` is empty for the *favicons*.

### Method 1) Using the `wp_mime_type_icon` filter

The mime type for favicons is `image/x-icon`.

I managed to display the `.ico` files in the *Media Grid* view with:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mime_type_icon', function( $icon, $mime, $post_id )
{
    if( $src = false || 'image/x-icon' === $mime && $post_id > 0 )
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id );

    return is_array( $src ) ? array_shift( $src ) : $icon;
}, 10, 3 );
```

where it's important here to keep the third parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` as `$icon = false` (by default) to avoid an infinite loop!

The favicons are then displayed like this:

[image: Modifed version #1]

### Method 2) Using the `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` filter

When we load the media grid view, we make a call to the `wp_ajax_query_attachments` handler. It performs the following attachments query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $query );
$posts = array_map( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', $query->posts );
```

In this `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` function, various information is added to the `WP_Post` posts and they're filtered with:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', $response, $attachment, $meta );
```

where the output is the `$response` array.

We can use this filter to add the missing sizes for the favicons:

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', function( $response, $attachment, $meta )
{
    if( 'image/x-icon' === $response['mime'] 
         && isset( $response['url'] )
         && ! isset( $response['sizes']['full'] )
    )
    {
            $response['sizes'] = array( 'full' => array( 'url' => $response['url'] ) );
    }   
   return $response;
}, 10, 3 );
```

and they will then show up like this:

[image: Modification #2]

Notice that we only set the `url` part and not the `width`, `height` and `orientation`. We could further extend the solution to add this data, with the help of the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function, for example. But I leave that up to you ;-)

### Some `$response` examples:

Here's an example of the `$response` array for the `favicon.ico` file:

```
Array 
(
    [id] => 803
    [title] => favicon
    [filename] => favicon.ico
    [url] => http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/favicon.ico
    [link] => http://example.tld/?attachment_id=803
    [alt] => 
    [author] => 11
    [description] => 
    [caption] => 
    [name] => favicon
    [status] => inherit
    [uploadedTo] => 0
    [date] => 1423791136000
    [modified] => 1423791136000
    [menuOrder] => 0
    [mime] => image/x-icon
    [type] => image
    [subtype] => x-icon
    [icon] => http://example.tld/wp-includes/images/media/default.png
    [dateFormatted] => February 13, 2015
    [nonces] => Array
        (
            [update] => 4fac983f49
            [delete] => efd563466d
            [edit] => df266bf556
        )

    [editLink] => http://example.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=803&action=edit
    [meta] => 
    [authorName] => someuser
    [filesizeInBytes] => 1406
    [filesizeHumanReadable] => 1 kB
    [compat] => Array
        (
            [item] => 
            [meta] => 
        )

)
```

Here's an example for the `WordPress-Logo.jpg` image:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 733
    [title] => WordPress-Logo
    [filename] => WordPress-Logo.jpg
    [url] => http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/WordPress-Logo.jpg
    [link] => http://example.tld/2015/02/10/test/wordpress-logo/
    [alt] => 
    [author] => 1
    [description] =>
    [caption] =>
    [name] =>  wordpress-logo
    [status] => inherit
    [uploadedTo] => 784
    [date] => 1423314735000
    [modified] => 1423571320000
    [menuOrder] => 0
    [mime] => image/jpeg
    [type] => image
    [subtype] => jpeg
    [icon] => http://example.tld/wp-includes/images/media/default.png
    [dateFormatted] => February 7, 2015
    [nonces] => Array
        (
            [update] => cb6a4bca10
            [delete] => 068a4d3897
            [edit] => 14b7d201ff
        )

    [editLink] => http://example.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=733&action=edit
    [meta] => 
    [authorName] => someuser
    [uploadedToLink] => http://example.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=784&action=edit
    [uploadedToTitle] => 20150209021847
    [filesizeInBytes] => 127668
    [filesizeHumanReadable] => 125 kB
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [height] => 150
                    [width] => 150
                    [url] => http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/WordPress-Logo-150x150.jpg
                    [orientation] => landscape
                )

            [medium] => Array
                (
                    [height] => 184
                    [width] => 300
                    [url] => http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/WordPress-Logo-300x184.jpg
                    [orientation] => landscape
                )

            [full] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/WordPress-Logo.jpg
                    [height] => 620
                    [width] => 1010
                    [orientation] => landscape
                )

        )

    [height] => 620
    [width] => 1010
    [orientation] => landscape
    [compat] => Array
        (
            [item] => 
            [meta] => 
        )

)
```

ps: We are specifically interested in the `$response['size']` part of these examples.