# Where do the favicons for Media Files come from

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, pdf, favicon

I have uploaded some PDFs to the Media Library.

I cannot find a way to set the browser favicon for the PDF media files.

Where does WordPress get the favicon from?

Is there anyway to control the PDF Media file favicon?

Comment: There should not be a favicon for a PDF file, a favicon is generaly for the whole site. If you mean something else please explain.

Comment: Ah, but there is in Google Chrome.  Explanation: the "favicon" is the 16x16 graphic image that appears in the browser title tab.

Comment: so if you write an html page, host your PDF on some non wordpress server, what do you need to do to set a specific favicon for a PDF which is different then the sites favicon?

Comment: Let's try this @MarkKaplun. (1) Logon to the page in question at http://bit.ly/1FATyb2 (you will need to agree to the pop-up terms -- no worries, it only writes a cookie to your machine which you an clear afterwards). (2) Visually observe the page's favicon. (3) click on any one of the 3 PDF documents. (4) Observe the new favicon. Question: Where did WordPress or the browser get that favicon from ?

Comment: what I see is a site favicon and you don't even need to do anything as controlling it is part of version 4.3

Comment: Sounds just like what I need. Can you explain how to do this @MarkKaplun using 4.3. I'm at 4.3.1

Comment: it is the "site icon" under "site identity" in the cusromizer

Comment: I was hopeful about that being the answer @MarkKaplun but that did not render successfully as the base favicon for the PDF media files.

Comment: Then it is a browser bug, or what you request has no applicable standartd. favicon.ico is an old hack that was good for the old simple web, but it is not good any longer as web site structure become more complex and access to server files more restricted. The standard based replacement  for it requires serving an HTML page which specifies in its meta what image to use for favicon (and this is what 4.3 does). The problem of course is that pdf is not html and therefor there is no way to specify a favicon specifically for a single PDF file.

Comment: If you're getting a conflict between your WP site having one favicon and your uploads folder having another, check that you don't have an older favicon.ico lingering in your root directory while your new one was added via the WP site admin. Just encountered this on a site.

Comment: Simply upload Your desired favicon.ico to websait root folder. Then refresh .pdf page or clear all caches. Just tested in Wordpress 5.4 and it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments, the answer for the question as it is asked is that it is not possible. The web standards as they are right now do not have a facility to declare a favicon for PDF files, only for the whole domain via the favicon.ico file.

You can try to hack around it by

1. set the favicon.ico at the root of the site to the icon you want to be associated with media files and use the wordpress 4.3 site icon feature to handle the icon for the html (which should have priority over the favicon.ico).
2. server the media files from a different domain (for example a subdomain of the main site) and set there a favicon.ico that you want to be associated with the media files.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think you only need to modify the `favicon.ico` file in your WordPress root directory.

### Previous answer:

I guess you want to change this icon (`/wp-includes/images/media/document.png`):

[image: icon]

that shows up for PDF documents in the `Media Library`.

You could then use the `wp_mime_type_icon` filter to change the icon:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mime_type_icon', function( $icon, $mime, $post_id )
{
    if( 'application/pdf' === $mime && $post_id > 0 )
        $icon = 'http://example.tld/pdf.png'; // Modify this to your needs!

    return $icon;
}, 10, 3 );
```

But for *favicons*, you can check out my [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177988/26350).

Comment: No, that's not the favicon that appears in the browser for me @birgire. See my most recent comment back to MarkKaplun above.

Comment: I just updated the answer, after reading your comment, please add all relevant info into the question itself, thanks @tammy

Comment: Ah, good tip @birgire, I'll check into that and post back.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is what's happening. Do you know if there is any "clever" way of overriding that? The reason is that the site that shows the "wrong" desired-favicon is only one site in the many multisite networks I am running. So I do not want to alter the base favicon. I merely want to set a favicon for this particular MS network site. Is that do-able @birgire?

Comment: I wonder if you could try rewriting the favicon.ico requests (via nginx or apache) on those specific sites? @tammy

Comment: Yeah, probably. I'm actually looking into WP plugins at the moment as I gotta believe someone has already resolved this anomaly via a plugin. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To override it for bare file requests (like jpg, png, pdf, .. ) I think you can only do that at the nginx/apache level. So I think such a WP plugins, if they exists, would generate nginx.conf/.htaccess snippets for you. => I don't think there's a pure PHP workaround for this. @tammy

Comment: setting favicon is actually a feature of 4.3 and should work on all types of servers